# Back button using persistent_bottom_nav_bar

Tags: android, flutter

i am using the library persistent_bottom_nav_bar to manage my bottomBar in my flutter app, but when i return my Scaffold with an appBar static i customize the appBar, and in many screens i need a backButton, traditionaly i will be using Navigator.pop(context) to return before screen, but when i try in this app are closed.

how to create a backButton that is to level to PersistentTabView that i allow me return back to screen.
I thank you in advance for the help provided

this is my code:

**BottomBar:**

```
return MainScreen(
    children: PersistentTabView(
  context,
  controller: Provider.of<MenuProvider>(context, listen: true).controller,
  screens: _buildScreens(),
  items: _navBarsItems(),
  confineInSafeArea: true,
  backgroundColor:
      AppColors.of(context).greyBottomBar, // Default is Colors.white.
  handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, // Default is true.
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  padding: NavBarPadding.all(0),
  bottomScreenMargin: 60,
  navBarHeight: 65,
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
      true, // This needs to be true if you want to move up the screen when keyboard appears. Default is true.
  stateManagement: true, // Default is true.
  hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows:
      true, // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument. Default is true.
  decoration: const NavBarDecoration(
    colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
  ),
  popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
  popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
  itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(
    // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    curve: Curves.ease,
  ),
  screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
    // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.
    animateTabTransition: true,
    curve: Curves.ease,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  ),
  },
  navBarStyle:
      NavBarStyle.style3, // Choose the nav bar style with this property.
));
```

**MainScreen:**

```
return CustomModalWidgetScaffold(
            scaffoldKey: cubit.scaffoldKey,
            bottom: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
                child: StreamBuilder<Widget?>(
                    initialData: Container(),
                    stream: cubit.observerSearchBar,
                    builder: (context, snapShot) {
                      return value.showSearchBar
                          ? Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                              child: CustomSearchBar(
                              ),
                            )
                          : Container();
                    })),
            body: widget.children,
          );
```